# Iterating through DateTimeIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame with an index that is a series of consecutive dates. I am trying to iterate through the dates, but I am being thrown a KeyError, where I know the key given exists and is in the correct format (Pandas Timestamp)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

## Importing the data from the Sep 2016-August 2018
## Step count & Date features only

features = ['Date','Step count']
data = pd.read_csv('fit_daily_sum_Sep2016_Aug2018.csv', sep=',', usecols=features).set_index('Date')
# To convert data index to datetime
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)

tmp = data.head()
print tmp.index
print 'first key',tmp.index[0]
print type(tmp.index[0])

fkey = pd.Timestamp(2016,9,2)
print 'fkey is',fkey
for x in xrange(0, len(tmp)):
    print 'running',fkey+datetime.timedelta(days=x)
    print tmp[fkey+datetime.timedelta(days=x)]
```

The first iteration of the final line throws a KeyError. Console shows as below (condensed)

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-09-02', '2016-09-03', '2016-09-04', '2016-09-05',
           '2016-09-06'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', freq=None)
first key 2016-09-02 00:00:00
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
fkey is 2016-09-02 00:00:00
running 2016-09-02 00:00:00
KeyError: Timestamp('2016-09-02 00:00:00')
```

It seems to me that I am feeding in the precise key which I know exists, yet is throwing a KeyError! I am not sure where the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to use a loop here, could you include a sample of your dataframe, as well as the desired output dataframe in your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
tmp[fkey+datetime.timedelta(days=x)]
```

This portion is looking at your dataFrame's column heading, not the index.

Try

```py
tmp.loc(fkey+datetime.timedelta(days=x))
```

or

```py
tmp['Step count'][fkey+datetime.timedelta(days=x)]
#where 'Step count' is the column name of interest.
```

Comment: This is almost correct! I assume it would work if `tmp` was a Pandas Series but it is in fact a DataFrame. So, the way to get this to work is tmp['Step count'][fkey+datetime.timedelta(days=x)] where 'Step count' is the column name of interest. Or doing a similar thing using the loc function as you suggested

Comment: If you edit your answer with the above information I'd be happy to mark it as correct, as the crux of your answer led me to this solution!